# How exactly do Commands get notified to execute their CanExecute?

Tags: wpf, icommand

Imagine, you have a simple WPF window with just a `TextBox` and a `Button` on it. The `TextBox`'s `Text` property is bound to a property called `FileName` and the `Button`'s `Command` property is bound to a property called `ImportCommand`.

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding FileName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <Button Content="Import" Command="{Binding ImportCommand}" />
</StackPanel>
```

The view model is pretty much boiler plate code as well.

```
Public Class MainViewModel
    Inherits ObservableItem

    Private _fileName As String
    Private _importCommand As ICommand = New RelayCommand(AddressOf Me.Import, AddressOf Me.CanImport)

    Public Sub New()
        Me.FileName = "C:\Temp\temp.dat"
    End Sub

    Public Property FileName As String
        Get
            Return _fileName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            MyBase.SetProperty(Of String)(_fileName, value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property ImportCommand As ICommand
        Get
            Return _importCommand
        End Get
    End Property

    Private Sub Import()
        Throw New NotImplementedException
    End Sub

    Private Function CanImport() As Boolean
        Return Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.FileName) AndAlso IO.File.Exists(Me.FileName)
    End Function

End Class
```

There's no obvious connection between the `TextBox` and the `Button`, and there's no obvious connection between the `FileName` property and the `ImportCommand`.

So, how does the `ImportCommand` detect, that I may have changed the `FileName` property and that this change may affect the enabled state of the `Button`, the `ImportCommand` is bound to?

Does WPF call `CanExecute` on **any** `Command` and **any** `PropertyChanged` that's happening? Sounds like a lot of unnecessary work to me?

Comment: So in your example you want to enable/disable Button based on the value of Filename?

Comment: No, the button should only be enabled when the user entered the name and path of an existing file. It's working, I just like to know why and how.

Comment: The short answer is user input. You click something or type text into a field then it will be checked. You could prove that to yourself by sticking debug.writeline in your canexecute and keep an eye on the output window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CanExecuteChanged event from the RelayCommad listens to the CommandManager.RequerySuggested event that is raised by the CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested method.

The CommandManager again listens to the InputManager KeyUp MouseUp or GotKeyboardFocus or LostKeyboardFocus events and calls InvalidateRequerySuggested to notify the UI to call the CanExecute method of the Command.

Comment: That sounds like a lot of unnecessary calls to CanExecute to me, but somehow it seems to work.